# Configurar gxmessage: intltool >= 0.50.0... found: error: Your intltool is too old. You need intltool 0.50.0 or later

Tags: compilar, configuración, gtk

Estoy tratando de compilar `gxmessage` y me aparece el error, de que `intltool` tiene una versión antigua a pesar de que inmediatamente antes, aparece que encontró la versión buscada.

Errores:

> HiRes.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xeb00080, needed 0xcd00080)
> checking for intltool >= 0.50.0...  found
> configure: error: Your intltool is too old.  You need intltool 0.50.0 or later.

***configure:1654*** (no entiendo cómo funciona el comando `test`)

```sh
case "$am__api_version" in
    1.01234)
    as_fn_error $? "Automake 1.5 or newer is required to use intltool" "$LINENO" 5
    ;;
    *)
    ;;
esac

INTLTOOL_REQUIRED_VERSION_AS_INT=`echo 0.50.0 | awk -F. '{ print $ 1 * 1000 + $ 2 * 100 + $ 3; }'`
INTLTOOL_APPLIED_VERSION=`intltool-update --version | head -1 | cut -d" " -f3`
INTLTOOL_APPLIED_VERSION_AS_INT=`echo $INTLTOOL_APPLIED_VERSION | awk -F. '{ print $ 1 * 1000 + $ 2 * 100 + $ 3; }'`
if test -n "0.50.0"; then
    { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for intltool >= 0.50.0" >&5
$as_echo_n "checking for intltool >= 0.50.0... " >&6; }
    { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: $INTLTOOL_APPLIED_VERSION found" >&5
$as_echo "$INTLTOOL_APPLIED_VERSION found" >&6; }
    test "$INTLTOOL_APPLIED_VERSION_AS_INT" -ge "$INTLTOOL_REQUIRED_VERSION_AS_INT" ||
    as_fn_error $? "Your intltool is too old.  You need intltool 0.50.0 or later." "$LINENO" 5
fi
```

Además en el `configure` aclara que fue generado con *Autoconf 2.69* (si intento ejecutarlo yo no me funciona por un problema del `Dumper.c`):

```sh
#! /bin/sh
# Guess values for system-dependent variables and create Makefiles.
# Generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69 for GNU gxmessage 3.4.3.
#
#
# Copyright (C) 1992-1996, 1998-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
#
#
# This configure script is free software; the Free Software Foundation
# gives unlimited permission to copy, distribute and modify it.
```

Descubrí que el problema aparece en `intltool-update:38`:

```
use File::Copy;
use File::Find;
```

El error es el siguiente:

> ListUtil.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xeb00080, needed 0xcd00080)

Registro:

```sh
~/documentos/programar/c/gxmessage-3.4.3 ./configure 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking for LC_MESSAGES... yes
checking libintl.h usability... yes
checking libintl.h presence... yes
checking for libintl.h... yes
checking for ngettext in libc... yes
checking for dgettext in libc... yes
checking for bind_textdomain_codeset... yes
checking for msgfmt... no
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
HiRes.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xeb00080, needed 0xcd00080)
checking for intltool >= 0.50.0...  found
configure: error: Your intltool is too old.  You need intltool 0.50.0 or later.
```

¿Cómo soluciono esto?

Comment: Igual que el anterior tienes una versión antigua, descarga la versión del intltool que sea mayor o igual a la a la 0.50.0.  Deberías revisar los requerimientos del gxmessage porque la probabilidad que encuentres otro error parecido despues de instalar el intltool es alta.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Parece que es un problema de Perl, el `intltool-update` me pedía `HiRes.c`, ese lo pude solucionar instalando `Time-HiRes`, pero ahora me pide `ListUtil.c`, estoy tratando de solucionarlo.

Comment: Quizá esta  sí te sirva: https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/gxmessage/ . Las dependencia que se indican las debes  instalar si es que no la tienes

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Estoy mirando, y traté de instalar `desktop-file-utils` pero me salen los mismos errores que antes.

Comment: Que versión de linux tienes, creo que tienes que actualizar linux para que tenga un gcc antiguio. De lo contrario vas ir actualizando paquete por paquete hasta que te encuentres con uno que hace que no te carga el linux. ten cuidado en eso o instala un gxmessage mas antiguo porque estas instalando tambien la ultima versión.

Comment: Instala la versión 3.40.0 si tienes gtk3 o la 2.20 de gxmessage .

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Mi versión de Linux es _LxPupSc64-20.06 5.7.2-lxpup64_, se trata de un fork de _Slackware_... Lo que quiero es compilar `gxmessage` en vez de instalarlo y luego eso me ayudará a averiguar la solución al problema de que Glibc no soporta los _Locale_.

Comment: Instala o compila el gxmessage 2.20

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Es que ya tengo instalada la versión `2.20.4`, lo que quiero es compilar.

Comment: En los mensajes:m `gxmessage-3.4.3 `

Comment: Pero estás queriendo compilar la 3.4.3, por eso te digo que compiles la 2.20.4

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich En la página de la _Free Software Fundation_ [solo está para descargar esa versión](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Gxmessage), ¿Dónde puedo encontrar el código de la versión `2.20` para poder compilarla?

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionarlo, primero hay que instalar los paquetes de *Perl*, `Time-HiRes`, `plistutil`, `perl-Scalar-List-Utils`, y la librería `libplist3`.

Paquetes de Perl:

- Time-HiRes: http://abf-downloads.openmandriva.org/cooker/repository/x86_64/main/release/perl-Time-HiRes-1.9764-17-omv4040.x86_64.rpm
- plistutil: https://ftp.lysator.liu.se/pub/opensuse/tumbleweed/repo/oss/x86_64/plistutil-2.2.0-1.5.x86_64.rpm
- *perl-Scalar-List-Utils*: http://abf-downloads.openmandriva.org/cooker/repository/x86_64/main/release/perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.50-17-omv4040.x86_64.rpm

Librerías:

- libplist3: http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libp/libplist/

Si el instalador falla en alguno de estos paquetes, instalarlo manualmente abriendo los archivos *RPM* con *File-Roller*.

Una vez instalado el paquete `perl-Scalar-List-Utils`, hay que copiar una carpeta y editar un archivo.

```
cp -vfr /usr/lib64/perl5/List /usr/local/lib64/perl5
```

Ahora hay que editar el archivo `/usr/local/lib64/perl5/List/Util.pm` en la *línea 24*, cambiar lo siguiente:

```
XSLoader::load('List::Util', $XS_VERSION);
```

Y dejar comentada la línea o eliminarla:

```sh
# XSLoader::load('List::Util', $XS_VERSION);
```

Con eso ya no debería tirar ese error.

Librerías que requiere *File-Roller* (entre ellas `libjson`):

```
ldd /initrd/mnt/dev_save/sfs/file-roller/usr/bin/file-roller
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc34ffd000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f75e34ec000)
    libgtk-3.so.0 => /lib64/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007f75e2d5a000)
    libgdk-3.so.0 => /lib64/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007f75e2c58000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f75e2c10000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f75e2adb000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f75e2ab4000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f75e28ed000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f75e288f000)
    libjson-glib-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libjson-glib-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f75e2863000)
    libnotify.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libnotify.so.4 (0x00007f75e2859000)
    libarchive.so.13 => /usr/lib64/libarchive.so.13 (0x00007f75e2797000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f75e2775000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f75e2587000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f75e2514000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f75e250e000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f75e24fe000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f75e23fa000)
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f75e23e3000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f75e2399000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f75e22d9000)
    libfribidi.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libfribidi.so.0 (0x00007f75e22bb000)
    libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007f75e22af000)
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f75e2285000)
    libepoxy.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libepoxy.so.0 (0x00007f75e2150000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f75e2000000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f75e1fed000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f75e1ead000)
    libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f75e1e76000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f75e1c70000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f75e1c65000)
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => /lib64/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f75e1c21000)
    libwayland-client.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f75e1c10000)
    libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007f75e1c06000)
    libwayland-egl.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007f75e1c01000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f75e1bed000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f75e1be1000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f75e1bda000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f75e1bd5000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f75e1bc8000)
    libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f75e19c5000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f75e19c0000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f75e1917000)
    libEGL.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libEGL.so.1 (0x00007f75e1902000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f75e18fb000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib64/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f75e18c6000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f75e18c1000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f75e1898000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f75e1886000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f75e167c000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f75e1465000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f75e13d7000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib64/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f75e137c000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f75e1361000)
    libffi.so.7 => /usr/lib64/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f75e1353000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f75e1073000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f75e0e6b000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f75e0e43000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007f75e0d5f000)
    libbz2.so.1 => /lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007f75e0d4c000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f75e09e3000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f75e3615000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f75e09ba000)
    libbrotlidec.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007f75e09ac000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f75e0959000)
    libatspi.so.0 => /lib64/libatspi.so.0 (0x00007f75e0727000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f75e066e000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f75e0669000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f75e0661000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f75e062e000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib64/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f75e05dd000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f75e03d8000)
    libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007f75e03b5000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib64/../lib64/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f75e03aa000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f75e03a1000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib64/../lib64/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f75e0381000)
```